# Use Custom Post Type archive page for the taxonomies term archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

In my wordpress theme I created a new custom post type 'books' with 2 taxonomies ('series', 'genres'). when I visit the archive of the cpt 'books' (site.com/books), I list all the books.

I added a custom frontend filter to get in this archive page books by taxonomy terms by passing an argument to the url with the name of the taxonomy and the terme (like this: site.com/books/?genres=action). Like a book browser.

But wordpress is by default creating the link for my taxonomies like this (site.com/genres/action/) and i want it to be "redirected" to the books post type with the taxonomy argument (site.com/books/?genres=action).

Is it possible to achieve that ? Thank you

**Update**

Actually I'm using this "workaround" :

```
// Change url link for term of taxonomies of CPT Book
function cpt_book_term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( in_array($taxonomy, get_object_taxonomies('books')) ) {
        $url = home_url() . '/books/?'. $taxonomy . '=' . $term->slug;
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'cpt_book_term_link_filter', 10, 3 );
```

With this I edit each taxonomies terms of the Custom Post Type book and change it to link to my Custom Post Type book archive's page.

But I don't think it's the best solution. Because archives page for my taxonomies (books/genres/action, ...) still exist and are used for canonical url in plugins like yoast seo. I can force to redirect them but I don't think its good.

Comment: You're reusing an existing queryvar, if you visit `site.com/genres/action` it gets processed into `index.php?genres=action`, so `site.com/books/?genre=action` doesn't look any different to it. Is there a reason you don't just prefix the genres taxonomy with `books/` so it has a `books/genres/action` URL? Then you can just use `get_term_link` and have nicer URLs, and the ability to have dedicated book genre archive templates? Even the filter would be easier to implement as you could just call one of the native WP functions like tag cloud or the dropdown?

Comment: Don't forget, you can add `?s=` on the end of any archive to search it

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'am not prefixing with book and usigng ?s= because i want to crate a "global books browser" where i can search by multiple and different taxonomies at the same time and even combined with custom meta. All this in a single page.

Comment: Note that your custom meta should be a taxonomy if you intend to search or filter based on that data. Searching/Filtering for posts via their post meta is extremely expensive and gets slower as the number of posts increases, this is because normal queries can be super fast and rely on table indexes, but the post meta table was never built to make those kinds of queries fast. If it was, tags and categories would be post meta. That's why they built dedicated tables for filtering grouping and searching, aka taxonomies and terms.

Comment: Most field plugins such as ACF/Field manager/etc provide options for using a taxonomy instead of post meta to save the data, look up their documentation for how

Comment: @tom Yes i see what you mean, the meta that i use is a date (release date) i can't use it like a taxonomy. For the plugin i'm triying to avoid using one.

Comment: That's not true, you can use a taxnomy and create terms for years and months and auto-assign them on post save, allowing you to filter by a year/month but also display the full value from post meta when listing the post. Such a system would be orders of magnitude faster than a date based meta query, and scale to a much much larger number of visitors. It may seem like you have to use post meta, but the truth is you have lots of alternative options to enhance or replace it.

Comment: In the meantime, I tried to reproduce your bug using a talk post type with a talk tags taxonomy, but the behaviour you described of redirecting the URL to the taxonomy terms archive did not occur, e.g. https://tomjn.com/talks/?tomjn_talk_tag=blocks does not redirect to https://tomjn.com/talktags/blocks/ on my own site. Can you include the code for your filter as well as the registration of the CPT and taxonomy in your question? I'm assuming your book archive is a real archive and not a page template?

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. I'm not saying that this url: /books?genres=action redirects to this url: /genres/action. But I want that when I go to the taxonomy archive (/genres/action) I am redirected to my custom post type archive page with the additional parameter "books/?genres=action". For example : [https://psblog.fr/jeux/?plateforme=ps4](https://psblog.fr/jeux/?plateforme=ps4)